# Is there any use of Claytronics in Star Wars lore?

Tags: star-wars

Are [Claytronics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claytronics), Catoms or Programmable Matter featured or mentioned in any canon expanded universe source?   I have found no references to them in [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page).

Comment: Not likely. Read Nanotechnology article on Wookiepedia for reasons why.

Comment: This is [the article](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Nanotechnology) that DVK was referring to, I believe.  Just 'cause I'm guessing other people are as lazy as I sometimes am, and would rather not search themselves :)

Comment: @DVK - On the plus side I've worked out how to mass-search all the Star Wars EU books in one go.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE : So-called "Microdroids" play a part in the latest Marvel Star Wars comics "[Darth Vader #003](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/51670/darth_vader_2015_3)". Nanotech is now (officially) part of the [main Star Wars canon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Canon).

[image]

---

I've searched through the 250(ish) books that form the [Star Wars EU](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Expanded_Universe) and I can find no reference to the terms "*Claytronics*", "*Programmable matter*" or "*Catoms*".

There are some slight glancing references to nanotech in various Elizabeth Hand novels ("**Hunted**", "**A New Threat**", "**Pursuit**"), "**Rule of Two**" by Drew Karpyshyn "**The Swarm War**" and "**The Unseen Queen**" by Troy Denning and "**Hard Contact**" and "**True Colours**" by Karen Traviss.

Nanotechnology seems to mainly find use in slavery devices, bio-weaponry (nanoviruses), illegal medical devices, biological computing and forced terraforming. Whenever it's mentioned in the EU canon, there seems to be an underlying sense of ***wrongness*** either because it's a very *alien* form of technology (e.g. almost exclusively used outside the core worlds of the Galactic Republic) or because of the [grey goo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grey_goo) threat.